# Install a service without template

Tags: c#, service

I have made this windows service executable, but what do you do to install it. Everywhere where I look it says that you have to use a Visual Studio template, but I have Visual Studio Express which doesn't include this template. How can I still make an installer?

P.S. I have an installer class in the service, I just don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly I would throw away installers in services and rather use the [sc command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx). It lets you install and manage services much more easily.

> Communicates with the Service Controller and installed services.
>   SC.exe retrieves and sets control information about services. You can
>   use SC.exe for testing and debugging service programs. Service
>   properties stored in the registry can be set to control how service
>   applications are started at boot time and run as background processes.
>   SC.exe parameters can configure a specific service, retrieve the
>   current status of a service, as well as stop and start a service. You
>   can create batch files that call various SC.exe commands to automate
>   the startup or shutdown sequence of services. SC.exe provides
>   capabilities similar to Services in the Administrative Tools item in
>   Control Panel.

EDIT: To install the service, use the `sc create` command and specify your arguments:

```
sc create [ServiceName] start= [boot | system | auto | demand | disabled] binPath= "[Path to exe]" DisplayName= [Service Display Name]
```

- ServiceName   : Specifies the service name returned by the getkeyname operation.
- start= { boot | system | auto | demand | disabled } : Specifies the start type for the service. The default start is start= demand.
- binpath=   BinaryPathName   : Specifies a path to the service binary file. There is no default for binpath= and this string must be supplied.
- displayname=   DisplayName   : Specifies a friendly name that can be used by user-interface programs to identify the service.

Please go see [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) for a full list of parameters

Comment: It's not necessary, but if you want, can you give me any examples of how to use it?

Comment: I pasted the command above. You have to fill in some data that only you know, for example the binary path or how you want to call the service